# Resize down the container(height wise) with fixed dimensions without using max-width

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, responsive

I'm currently working on a NextJS project and facing a challenge with resizing a CV preview section. In my application, I have a parent component representing the CV preview section, and within it, there's a child component for the CV itself.

I want to implement a feature where I can resize the CV component without causing a shrink effect meaning the whole cv is resized-down , similar to what is demonstrated in this video: https://youtu.be/GDPP7GfQAuI

I have set a fixed width and height for the CV component to avoid formatting issues, and I'm hesitant to use max-width due to potential complications.

Could someone guide me on achieving this resizing functionality within NextJS? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tried adjusting CV component dimensions with tailwind cSS, but encountered a shrink effect that messes with the cv content on shrinking browser.I want to achieve dynamic resizing without shrinking

Here is the parent component code:

```
   <main className="flex-[1] h-full hidden lg:flex flex-col px-5 relative">
      <div>
        <TransformWrapper
          velocityAnimation={{
            sensitivity: 1,
          }}
          centerOnInit
        >
          {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform }) => (
            <>
              <figure className="relative w-full h-full flex justify-center lg:items-center xl:items-start xl:top-5">
                <TransformComponent
                  wrapperStyle={{
                    height: "840px",
                  }}
                >
                  <Resume2
                    draggableSections={draggableSecions}
                    setDraggableSections={setDraggableSections}
                    forwardRef={templateRef}
                  />
                </TransformComponent>
              </figure>
              <ControlZoom
                zoomIn={zoomIn}
                zoomOut={zoomOut}
                resetZoom={resetTransform}
              />
            </>
          )}
        </TransformWrapper>
      </div>
      <div className="absolute left-[30%] xl:left-[43%] bottom-6 w-fit h-fit rounded-full">
        <div className="relative">
          <button
            onClick={exportPDF}
            className="bg-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-500 duration-300 text-white px-12 rounded-full py-2"
          >
            <span className="pr-3">Download</span>
          </button>
          <HiOutlineCloudDownload
            className="absolute cursor-pointer right-6 text-white top-3"
            size={20}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Here is child component(CV, I didnot included the code between it) :

```
 <div
        ref={forwardRef}
        id="template"
        className={`template w-[560px] pb-3 ${
          resumeHeight === undefined
            ? "h-[780px]"
            : resumeHeight > 780
            ? "h-[1560px]"
            : "h-[780px]"
        }`}
      >
   </div>
```

Tried using max-wdith but it dont serve the purpose, similarly used height with % with still didnot work